# targeting a specific package within a project through gradle dependencySubstitution

Tags: android, gradle, dependency-resolution

our project is a monolithic android application-- is currently relies on 2 different libraries to stream different video content, hls/dash and regular video content. the problem we're facing is that one of these libraries is actually just a wrapper around the other one, which led us down the path of hardcoding a dependency resolution strategy in the gradle to avoid duplicate library errors.

```
configurations.all { config ->     
    resolutionStrategy { 
        dependencySubstitution {             
            substitute module("com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:$exoplayerVersion") with module("com.axinom.sdk:exoplayer-library-core:$axinomVersion")      
        }
        cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds' // only affects snapshots   
    } 
}
```

the problem with this approach is that this will apply globally, even in the package that contains the hls/dash feature, say this package is located at "org.example.project.features.livetv". I want to conditionally apply the statement resolution strategy above everywhere except for this package.

How can I do this without modularizing the app into separate feature with their own gradle config?

1. I've tried adding a simple if-statement but that doesn't work as the substitution statement in itself will still apply globally, since there are no restrictions on it once the if-statement if met.
2. I've tried creating a separate configuration tied to the "livetv" package which will contain all the core dependencies as the app does but will not apply the substitution clause but I was getting all sorts of build errors from that-- probably because I'm not doing it correctly. See below:

```
// Define a custom configuration for the livetv package
configurations {
    livetvCompile
}

// Global substitution rule
configurations.all {
    if (name != 'livetvCompile') { // Apply substitution to all configurations except 'livetvCompile'
        resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
            substitute module("com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:$exoplayerVersion") with module("com.axinom.sdk:exoplayer-library-core:$axinomVersion")
        }
    }
}

// Dependencies for 'livetvCompile' configuration
configurations.livetvCompile {
    // Define dependencies specific to the 'livetv' package
    implementation("com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:$exoplayerVersion")
}

// Apply 'livetvCompile' configuration to the 'livetv' package
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
            exclude '**/livetv/**'
        }
    }
    livetv {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
            include '**/livetv/**'
        }
        compileClasspath += configurations.livetvCompile
    }
}
```